# Java function to upload files to Google Cloud Storage fails after updating package version

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a maven java project that iterates over the files of a directory and uploads them to google cloud storage bucket. The code is something similar to the following

```
public void uploadFiles(String projectId, String bucketName, Path sourceDirectory){
  var storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
  try(var files = java.nio.file.Files.walk(sourceDirectory)){
    files.forEach{ file-> {
       var blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, getBlobPath(file)); \\getBlobPath gets the relative path for the file in google cloud bucket
       var blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
       storage.createFrom(blobInfo, file, BlobWriteOption.detectContentType());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my pom

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
          <version>26.19.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope> 
        </dependency>            
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
 #All google libraries I am using in various parts of the project
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-nio</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This works fine, but if I update the version of libraries to latest(26.22.0) or any higher version at all (26.20.0), the upload fails with the following error (I have removed the url from the error message)

```
com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Client side data loss detected. Attempt to append to a resumable session with an offset higher than the backend has
|> PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/......
|> content-range: bytes 0--1/0
|  
|< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
|< content-length: 37
|< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
|< x-guploader-uploadid: 
|< 
|< Failed to parse Content-Range header.
|  
at com.google.cloud.storage.JsonResumableSessionFailureScenario.toStorageException(JsonResumableSessionFailureScenario.java:185)
at com.google.cloud.storage.JsonResumableSessionFailureScenario.toStorageException(JsonResumableSessionFailureScenario.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.storage.JsonResumableSessionPutTask.call(JsonResumableSessionPutTask.java:204)
at com.google.cloud.storage.JsonResumableSession.lambda$put$0(JsonResumableSession.java:81)
at com.google.cloud.storage.Retrying.lambda$run$0(Retrying.java:102)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.storage.Retrying.run(Retrying.java:99)
at com.google.cloud.storage.JsonResumableSession.put(JsonResumableSession.java:68)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.createFrom(StorageImpl.java:258)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.createFrom(StorageImpl.java:224)
```

I could not find any explanation or anyone having similar issues after searching. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the picture and added the error as text.

Comment: @TahjidAshfaque, can you check if this [troubleshooting link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#400_bad_request) wherein you need `Content-Range: bytes */*` to be specified?

Comment: @RobertG, thank you for the suggestion, I wasn't able to find out how to set content range when I am using a client library function, but looking into that gave me the solution of inputstream instead of the Path to the source file directly and that worked.

Comment: @TahjidAshfaque, please post your comment as answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to get it working by changing to using inputstream instead of the Path to source.

```
public void uploadFiles(String projectId, String bucketName, Path sourceDirectory){
  var storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
  try(var files = java.nio.file.Files.walk(sourceDirectory)){
    files.forEach{ file-> {
       var blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, getBlobPath(file)); \\getBlobPath gets the relative path for the file in google cloud bucket
       var blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
       storage.createFrom(blobInfo, new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file)), BlobWriteOption.detectContentType());
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and no info available. I have not tried InputStream route yet